# Consulta SQL cambiar numero por valor de tabla

Tags: sql

tengo dos tablas en mi BD. En la tabla A tengo una referencia numérica a un valor de la tabla B, es decir, la estructura es la siguiente:

> **TABLA A**
>
> *Columnas*: Nombre | Apellido | Tipo_Contrato
>
> *Valores que tengo en mi BD para estas columnas (p. ej.)*: Juan | Díaz | 1

> **TABLA B**
>
> *Columnas*: Tipo | Descripcion
>
> *Valores*: 1 | Temporal

Lo que quiero es una consulta que me traiga todos los datos de la Tabla A, pero sustituya el "1" por "Temporal". Esto se debe a que quiero recoger esta información desde una app PHP. Podría hacer dos consultas desde la app, pero para optimizar me gustaría hacerlo desde SQL con una sola consulta, si es que es posible.

He probado con INNER JOIN pero, obviamente, no sustituye el valor.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda. Gracias. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Qué INNER JOIN has intentado? ¿Qué es eso de que no sustituye el valor? Si sacas como resultado NOMBRE, APELLIDO, DESCRIPCION cuando A.TIPO_CONTRATO = B.TIPO ¿no te vale?

Comment: Puedes agregar la consulta con INNER JOIN que has intentado para guiarte.

Comment: Ya Intentaste INNER JOIN y CASE WHEN ? me parece que eso es lo que necesitas

Answer (score 1):

@RubioRic tiene razón, ¿no has probado algo así?

```
SELECT A.Nombre, A.Apellido, B.Descripcion
FROM [TABLA A] as A INNER JOIN [TABLA B] as B ON A.Tipo_Contrato = B.Tipo
```

Comment: Exactamente eso es lo que necesitaba, intentaba el inner join pero cogiendo b.tipo en vez de b.descripcion. Muchas gracias!!